# How to get the selected text's size(px) and font weight?

Tags: autohotkey, text-size

I am trying to get selected text's size(pixel) and font weight(pt) with AutoHotkey like HTML attributes. How do I do?

I have done some search on google and have found this:
[Function: GetTextSize - Calculate text dimension](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/16625-function-gettextsize-calculate-text-dimension/)

But every text have its own font-type and how this code works correctly for other font types?

Comment: document.getElementById("myP").style.fontWeight will give you font weight

Comment: Thanks.How about other applications such as notepad,microsoft word? I want to get any selected text font-weight and size.